# Hide / ignore the packets you are creating in iptables firewall when connected with ssh into a Linux machine?

Tags: iptables, monitoring

If I'm using SSH to remote into a machine and I'm running a command like: `sudo iptables -L -v -n` how do I get a packet hit count that excludes the packet traffic I'm creating by using SSH?

I mean I could just avoid that by logging in to the machine directly, but I doubt that is always the case...or do I just have to add a rule to catch the specific type of traffic I want to monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to add a separate rule for your SSH connections, so that they do not mix with the other flows. Something like this:

```
-A INPUT -s <your client IP address> -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

You can also remove the IP address match if you want to separate all SSH traffic, add a match for a particular interface, etc.